# Returning and printing array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having issues pushing an object into and array and printing out that array and its individual object elements.
The following function tries to create an array of object and returns it.

```
function idPosition()
{
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    result.push({'id': i, 'position': i + 1});
  return result;
}
alert(idPosition());
console.log(idPosition());
```

However, the `alert()` output always seems to be `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` and the `console.log()` output is `Array [ Object, Object, Object ]`

How can I return the array of records such that `result = [{'id':0 , 'position':1},{'id':1 , 'position':2},{'id':2 , 'position':3}]`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Um, you have the array.... That is how it is displayed with .toString(). Do you just want to see it? `console.log(JSON.stringify(idPosition()));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `JSON.stringify()`

```js
function idPosition()
{
  var result=[]
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    result.push({'id': i, 'position':i+1})
  return JSON.stringify(result)
}
alert(idPosition())
console.log(idPosition())
```